# Strange MissingTemplate exception with :formats=>[:jpeg, "image/pjpeg", :png, :gif]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, mime-types

In production, we regularly get the following exception:

> An ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in constructions#show:
>
> Missing template constructions/show, application/show with {:locale=3D>[:=
>   ru], :formats=3D>[:jpeg, "image/pjpeg", :png, :gif], :handlers=3D>[:erb, :b=
>   uilder, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}

What puzzles me here is the formats hash, which requests for some image (:jpeg, "image/pjpeg", :png, :gif). We have no custom MIME types registered in our app, and as far as I know there's no corresponding Rails default MIME-type.

So the question is: what kind of request generates this formats hash?

Comment: Please include your controller and the view that makes the request

Answer (score 2):

I got same error as well. I notices this is from a search engine of "YandexImage" trying to get custom format. On my controller and action is just empty, because it is a static *.html.erb page. Here is more information.

```
* DOCUMENT_ROOT : /srv/www/apps/mysite/current/public 
* HTTP_ACCEPT : image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png, image/gif 
* HTTP_CONNECTION : Keep-Alive 
* HTTP_FROM : support@search.yandex.ru 
* HTTP_HOST : mysite.com 
* HTTP_USER_AGENT : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexImages/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots) 
* ORIGINAL_FULLPATH : /
```

Two ways to fix this:

Edit public/robots.txt to block YandexImage. see more information at http://yandex.com/bots

```
User-agent: YandexImage 
Disallow: /
```

Or put following code to your action, it will handle only html otherwise raise the not found page

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.any { raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') }
end
```